# Error while upgrading superset to 2.0.0 psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn

Tags: python, postgresql, openshift, apache-superset

After updating superset to 2.0.0 I cannot access sqllab nor view databases (Oracle DB).

I'm running superset on openshift with custom image built from `apache/superset:2.0.0`
Installed dependencies:

```
cx_Oracle certifi flask-oidc==1.4.0 flask_openid gevent psycopg2 psycopg2-binary==2.9.1 redis==3.5.3 itsdangerous==2.0.1
```

I tried running `superset db upgrade` with following result:

```
$ superset db upgrade
Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/app/pythonpath/superset_config.py]
logging was configured successfully
2022-11-21 14:21:41,835:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2022-11-21 14:21:41,841:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

and `superset init` throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column dbs.allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch does not exist
LINE 1: ..., dbs.force_ctas_schema AS dbs_force_ctas_schema, dbs.allow_...
^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 33, in \<module\>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
return self.main(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 601, in main
return super().main(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
return \_process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, \*\*ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
return \__callback(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 445, in decorator
return \__ctx.invoke(f, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
return \__callback(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 445, in decorator
return \__ctx.invoke(f, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
return _callback(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "/app/superset/cli/main.py", line 62, in init
security_manager.sync_role_definitions()
File "/app/superset/security/manager.py", line 731, in sync_role_definitions
self.create_missing_perms()
File "/app/superset/security/manager.py", line 679, in create_missing_perms
merge_pv("datasource_access", datasource.get_perm())
File "/app/superset/connectors/sqla/models.py", line 826, in get_perm
if self.database is None:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 294, in __get__
return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 730, in get
value = self.callable(state, passive)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 759, in \_load_for_state
return self.\_emit_lazyload(
File "\<string\>", line 1, in \<lambda\>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 847, in \_emit_lazyload
q(session)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/baked.py", line 615, in \_load_on_pk_identity
result = list(bq.for_session(self.session).params(\*\*params))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/baked.py", line 444, in __iter__
return q.\_execute_and_instances(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3560, in \_execute_and_instances
result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self.\_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in \_execute_on_connection
return connection.\_execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in \_execute_clauseelement
ret = self.\_execute_context(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in \_execute_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise
raise exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column dbs.allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch does not exist
LINE 1: ..., dbs.force_ctas_schema AS dbs_force_ctas_schema, dbs.allow_...
^

\[SQL: SELECT dbs.uuid AS dbs_uuid, dbs.created_on AS dbs_created_on, dbs.changed_on AS dbs_changed_on, dbs.id AS dbs_id, dbs.verbose_name AS dbs_verbose_name, dbs.database_name AS dbs_database_name, dbs.sqlalchemy_uri AS dbs_sqlalchemy_uri, dbs.password AS dbs_password, dbs.cache_timeout AS dbs_cache_timeout, dbs.select_as_create_table_as AS dbs_select_as_create_table_as, dbs.expose_in_sqllab AS dbs_expose_in_sqllab, dbs.configuration_method AS dbs_configuration_method, dbs.allow_run_async AS dbs_allow_run_async, dbs.allow_file_upload AS dbs_allow_file_upload, dbs.allow_ctas AS dbs_allow_ctas, dbs.allow_cvas AS dbs_allow_cvas, dbs.allow_dml AS dbs_allow_dml, dbs.force_ctas_schema AS dbs_force_ctas_schema, dbs.allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch AS dbs_allow_multi_schema_metadata_fetch, dbs.extra AS dbs_extra, dbs.encrypted_extra AS dbs_encrypted_extra, dbs.impersonate_user AS dbs_impersonate_user, dbs.server_cert AS dbs_server_cert, dbs.is_managed_externally AS dbs_is_managed_externally, dbs.external_url AS dbs_external_url, dbs.created_by_fk AS dbs_created_by_fk, dbs.changed_by_fk AS dbs_changed_by_fk
FROM dbs
WHERE dbs.id = %(param_1)s\]
\[parameters: {'param_1': 1}\]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Anyone found solution for this error?

Tried:
superset db upgrade
superset init
updating dependencies
restarting superset

Expect:
successfully migrate to 2.0.0 version